# How i can add List of items to my RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android

in onLoadFinsih i get back from the server List of movies i want to

add this list to my RecyclerView adapter

i tried to create  List of movies and pass it to my RecyclerView adapter 
then when i get the list of movies from the server in onLoadFinish method i add
this list to the list that i passed in the adapter then notify the adapter 
but not working

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Movie>>{

        private RecyclerView.Adapter movieRecyclerViewAdapter;
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
        private List<Movie> mListOfMovies;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    mListOfMovies = new ArrayList<>();

    movieRecyclerViewAdapter = new MovieItemAdapter(this, mListOfMovies);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(movieRecyclerViewAdapter);

}
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Movie>> loader, List<Movie> movies) {
    //hide progress bar after fetch data from server
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    mListOfMovies.clear();

    mListOfMovies.addAll(movies);

    movieRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged();

}



public class MovieItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Movie> mListOfMovies;
private Context mContext;

public MovieItemAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> movies) {
    this.mListOfMovies = movies;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
            .inflate(R.layout.movie_list_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Movie movieItem = mListOfMovies.get(position);

    holder.moviePoster.setImageBitmap(movieItem.getBitmap());
    holder.movieName.setText(movieItem.getTitle());

    DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
    holder.voteAverage.setText(format.format(movieItem.getVoteAverage()));
    holder.releaseDate.setText(movieItem.getReleaseDate());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mListOfMovies.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView moviePoster;
    public TextView movieName;
    public TextView voteAverage;
    public TextView releaseDate;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        moviePoster = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_poster);
        movieName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.movie_name);
        voteAverage = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.vote_average);
        releaseDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.release_date);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

In `onLoadFinish()` you should update the list in your adapter with the received data.

Then you should call the adapter's `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

EDIT:

Create a method in adapter like

```
setMovieList(List<Movie> movies){
    mListOfMovies = movies;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and call it from `onLoadFinished()`:

```
movieRecyclerViewAdapter.setMovieList(mListOfMovies)
```

Comment: as I've written you should add the elements to the __Adapter__, now you just update the list itself.
Create a method in adapter like setMovieList(List<Movie> movies), and call it from onLoadFinished. The method body should be: mListOfMovies = movies

Comment: when i call this method in onLoadFinsh what should i pass the list that comes form the server or the list that i pass to adapter in onCreate method

Comment: try with the list comes from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Make your ViewHolder class non static in adapter class. Then check again.